# How to do 'Like' functionality in Android/Kotlin using Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

We have been doing a Social Media Android application with 'Like' functionality using Cloud Firestore database as backend. Currently I have a collection named 'posts' and each post-document has it's own sub-collection named 'Likes'. 'FirestorePagingAdapter' is used to listing all the post-document from 'posts' collection.
Now I am facing an issue on reading 'Likes' sub-collection with FirestorePagingAdapter. I want to read 'like count', the names of people who are liked a particular post and also want to check whether the current logged-in user is liked or not in that particular post.
This is my collection and sub-collection structure on Firestore database.

My collection Images are here: ['posts' collection with documents and their sub-collection 'Likes'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyomu.png)  ['Likes' sub-collection and its documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqGoR.png)

```
// Get posts from fire store
private fun setupAdapter(homeDao: B2CHomeDAO) {
    val parentID = homeDao.parentDetails[0].parentId
    val fireStoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val fireStoreCollection = fireStoreDB.collection("posts")
    val mQuery = fireStoreCollection.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("scheduledDate", Timestamp.now())
            .orderBy("scheduledDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

    // Init Paging Configuration
    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(15)
            .setPageSize(5)
            .build()

    // Init Adapter Configuration
    val options: FirestorePagingOptions<FirebasePostModel> = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<FirebasePostModel>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(mQuery, config, SnapshotParser<FirebasePostModel> { snapshot ->
                val post: FirebasePostModel? = snapshot.toObject(FirebasePostModel::class.java)
                post?.let {
                    it.docID = snapshot.id
                    it.likeCount = 100
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "FinalPostItem::" + post.toString())
                post!!
            })
            .build()

    // Instantiate Paging Adapter
    fireStorePageAdapter = object : FirestorePagingAdapter<FirebasePostModel, HomeVerticalViewHolder>(options), RecyclerViewItemClickListener {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeVerticalViewHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_b2c_home_vertical, parent, false)
            return HomeVerticalViewHolder(view, this)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: HomeVerticalViewHolder, position: Int, post: FirebasePostModel) {
            // Bind to ViewHolder
            viewHolder.bind(post, fireStoreDB, fireStorePageAdapter, parentID, position)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception) {
            super.onError(e)
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.message)
        }

        override fun onLoadingStateChanged(state: LoadingState) {
            when (state) {
                LoadingState.LOADING_INITIAL -> {
                    swipe_refresh_layout.isRefreshing = true
                }
                LoadingState.LOADING_MORE -> {
                    swipe_refresh_layout.isRefreshing = true
                }
                LoadingState.LOADED -> {
                    swipe_refresh_layout.isRefreshing = false
                }
                LoadingState.ERROR -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    swipe_refresh_layout.isRefreshing = false
                }
                LoadingState.FINISHED -> {
                    swipe_refresh_layout.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onRecyclerViewItemClick(view: View, postItemModel: FirebasePostModel) {
            if (view.toggle_btn_like.isChecked)
                viewModel.doLikeFunctionality(postItemModel.docID)
            else
                viewModel.doDislikeFunctionality(postItemModel.docID)
        }
    }
    recycler_vertical.adapter = fireStorePageAdapter
}
```

Comment: You can try firebase functions's transaction

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo Did you see my image attachments in the question? Pagination functionality is working perfectly, I want to show 'like count' and check whether the logged in user is liked or not for every post item. That is my concern.

Comment: @AnkitSuda But how can I do firebase functions' transaction with FirestorePagingAdapter? Can you suggest anything?